# exchanging $Q$ and $Q^c$ continuously

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have seen that the set of points of continuity of a continuous function between $R$ to $R$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set. Since $Q$ is not  $G_{\delta}$ it cannot be a set of continuity of such function. Instead my doubt is does there exists a continuous function from $R$ to $R$ which sends rationals to irrationals and irrationals to rationals? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Assume there exists such a function $f$. It cannot be constant, so there must exist two real numbers $c_1< c_2$ such that $f(c_1)\neq f(c_2)$. We can without loss of generality assume that $f(c_1)<f(c_2)$ (otherwise we consider $-f$ instead). Then by the intermediate value theorem, $f$ assumes all values in the interval $[f(c_1),f(c_2)]$ on the interval $[c_1,c_2]$. Now, the interval $[f(c_1),f(c_2)]$ contains uncountably many distinct irrational numbers, but all of these must be in the image $f(\mathbb Q)$ by hypothesis. But $f(\mathbb Q)$ is countable, which is a contradiction.

Comment: thanks. nice property and nice proof.